# Visual Studio creates empty folding blocks

Tags: visual-studio-2019

Every now and again Visual Studio creates an empty folding block in my documents.
I have not found a way to dispose of these blocks, my current solution is to push them to the bottom of the document.

Is there any way to dispose of said folding blocks?
I would also like to know what the source of this issue is, to see if i can avoid this in the future.

Edit:
A folding block is a group of lines that can be collapsed into one line ([Example of an empty folding block](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y1aZQ.png)).

Comment: What are "folding block"? Any screenshot?

Comment: I have edited my question and added a link to a screenshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is apart of the [Outlining](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/outlining?view=vs-2019) feature that Visual Studio implements.

You can adjust/turn off the outlining settings a few ways:

1. Go to Tools → Text Editor → Your Language → Advanced and then scroll to the Outlining Section to adjust the various settings.  Depending on what language you are in, the options may not be available.

[image: Tools menu]

2. Right click in the document you have open and go to "Outlining" and select Stop Outlining to disable it.  This is a per document level.

[image: Right click menu]

3. The hot key combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>.  This is also per document.

The empty blocks fall under the "Show outlining for code level constructs" setting as seen in the first screenshot.  Uncheck that box and they should go away.  Declaration level constructs are things like method blocks and class declarations.

Comment: Thank you! Disabling and re-enabling outlining got rid of the empty folding blocks!