# Get rid of rogue fold/unfold behavior in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

A fold is the region of the file that's enclosed by the line and hash marks topped by a + or - icon between the file contents and the line numbers. I believe the misunderstanding comes from me using Notepad++'s term for this feature.

I'm editing a .css file and am not sure how this fold appeared at the end of my file. I can't get rid of it because it's not associated with a brace or region. I assumed there was a whitespace character creating it, so I tried showing whitespace characters with `Ctrl+R`, `Ctrl+W` but nothing showed up relating to it. Now, every time I add new lines to the end of the file this fold gives me the option to fold from that arbitrary line through the rest of the file, even if new braces and regions are added with their own folds.

I also found [this question's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1483813/1093799) that suggests turning the Outlining off, but there's two problems with that:

1. It turns Outlining off the the *entire* file.
2. It hides the problem because when the file is reopened, the rogue fold appears again.

No new line at the end of the file, so nothing to fold:

[image: No new line at the end of the file, so nothing to fold.]

The fold consuming the end of the file:

[image: The fold consuming the end of the file]

Continues consuming the end of the file even with new fold groups:

[image: Continues consuming the end of the file even with new fold groups]

With some cuts, newlines, and deletes, I can move the fold up the file:

[image: With some cuts, newlines, and deletes, I can move the fold up the file]

With some similar manipulations, I can move the fold back to the end of the file:

[image: With some similar manipulations, I can move the fold back to the end of the file]

No matter what I do though, I can't *remove* the fold. Backspacing and deleting from the state in the last pic only moves the fold back up the file and will reappear when newlines are added at the end.

Edit 2: I found another one of the rogue folds on another #region tag higher in the file. These 2 folds only exist in this file as all my other .css files display their regions correctly.

I've also double checked these files in Notepad++, and it properly shows all foldable regions enclosed by curly braces, #region appears to be a Visual Studio format effect.

Edit 3: I've now discovered another rogue fold in an .html file that was occupying the same lines as a div (html elements act as their own curly brace sections). The strange thing about this one is that it doesn't consume the rest of the file. Instead it's hiding everything between two completely blank lines (after I moved it out of the div), which I suspect is what the other 2 mentioned in my previous edits are also doing, but I can't detach their ends from the end of file (for obvious reasons).

Comment: What exactly is a fold in the context of your question?  Please edit your question instead of submitting  temporary commentary.

Comment: @Ramhound I believe the misunderstanding comes from me using Notepad++'s term for this feature. See the edit.

Comment: Does this happen with any supported programming language?  This is happening with Visual Studio 2019 not Visual Studio Code?  I am just trying to understand if it's the editor that is the problem or perhaps Intelisense itself.  What add-ons do you have installed?  I presume this is with the current stable version of Visual Studio 2019 (16.5.1)?

Comment: Visual Studio 2019 16.4.6. I do not have Visual Studio Code. The extensions I've installed are: Text Macros for Visual Studio 2019, Line Endings Unifier, Toggle Comment, and Editor Guidelines; all were installed more than a month ago. This is the ONLY file, that I've noticed, that's doing this and the only time, that I've noticed, it started was today.